# Blocs not closing using AutoTabsScaffold from auto_route package

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc, auto-route

I'm using the auto_route package to implement a tab bar and bloc to provide states to my pages. My problem is that blocs don't close when navigating between tabs. It will open the cubit when selecting the tab the first time, but never close it.

Here's my code:

The AppRouter:

```
@AutoRouterConfig()
class AppRouter extends _$AppRouter {
  @override
  List<AutoRoute> get routes => [
        AutoRoute(
          path: '/',
          page: AppWrapperRoute.page,
          initial: true,
          children: [
            AutoRoute(
              path: 'tab',
              page: TabBarRoute.page,
              children: [
                AutoRoute(path: 'page1', page: Page1Route.page),
                AutoRoute(path: 'page2', page: Page2Route.page),
                AutoRoute(path: 'page3', page: ProfileRoute.page),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ];
}
```

The TabBar:

```
@RoutePage(name: 'TabBarRoute')
class AutoTapBar extends StatelessWidget {
  const AutoTapBar({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AutoTabsScaffold(
      routes: const [
        Page1Route(),
        Page2Route(),
        Page3Route(),
      ],
      bottomNavigationBuilder: (_, tabsRouter) {
        return BottomNavigationBar(
          currentIndex: tabsRouter.activeIndex,
          onTap: tabsRouter.setActiveIndex,
          items: const [
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.home),
              label: 'Page1',
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.streetview),
              label: 'Page2',
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.account_circle),
              label: 'Page3',
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Page3:

```
@RoutePage(name: 'ProfileRoute')
class Page3Screen extends StatelessWidget {
  const Page3Screen({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider(
      create: (_) => di.getIt<Page3ScreenCubit>(),
      child: const _Page3Screen(),
    );
  }
}
```

I googled and could't find any answer.

Answer (score 2):

Right after opening the question is found the solution...

You have to maintainState to false in your routes:

> ```
>             AutoRoute(
>               maintainState: false,
>               path: 'profile',
>               page: ProfileRoute.page,
>             ),
> ```